# Chain rule: $f(t)=e^{t\sin2t}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm missing a step somewhere on this: $$f(t)=e^{t\sin2t}.$$

I know I have to use the chain rule but I'm getting tripped up. here are my steps:

$\frac d{dx}(e^{t\sin2t})$

$e^{t\sin2t} \frac d{dx}(t\sin2t)$ which then becomes a product rule:

$e^{t\sin2t}  [\frac d{dx}(t)  (\sin2t) + \frac d{dx}(\sin2t) (t)]$

then the $\sin 2t$ needs the chain rule:

$(\sin2t)  \frac d{dx}(2t)$ the results of this are $2t\sin2t$ which I plug back in to the above equation:

$e^{t\sin2t}  [\frac d{dx}(t)  (\sin2t) + (t)  (2t\sin2t)]$
which gives me:

$e^{t\sin2t}  [(t\sin2t) + (2t^{2}\sin2t)]$

I get lost from here. The answer says its:

$F(t)=e^{t\sin2t}(2t\cos2t +\sin2t)$

Comment: Hint: The derivative of $\sin()$ is **not** $\sin()$ but ...

Comment: am I still deriving the result from the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, but why are you introducing $x$?

Comment: @grammatester  probably poor notation, I meant d/dt just to use derivative notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't use product rule correctly

> $(t\cdot \sin{2t})'=t'\sin{2}t+t(\sin{2}t)'=1\cdot\sin{2t}+t\cdot \cos{2t}\cdot 2$

because

> $(\sin{2t})'=\cos{2t} \cdot(2t)'=\cos2t \cdot2$

So you get:

> $e^{t\sin2t}(\sin{2t}+2t\cos{2t})$

Comment: thank you so much, I've been using the chain rule wrong all along. I kept forgetting to derive the initial stuff before multiplying by the derivative of the inside (g(x)) I think this will help me.

Comment: if you like the answer, you can accept it, and by the way you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

By the Chain Rule,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t\sin{2t}}\right) = e^{t\sin{2t}}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\sin{2t}\right)$$

But by the product rule,

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\sin{2t}\right) &= t\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(\sin2t) + \sin2t\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(t)\\
&=t\cdot2\cos2t + \sin2t\\
&= 2t\cos2t + \sin2t\end{align}$$

Hence

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t\sin{2t}}\right) = e^{t\sin{2t}}(2t\cos2t + \sin2t)$$